# Is there any way to modify message which Masstransit transfers into _error queue?

Tags: masstransit

I have a message contract similar like this:

```
public class Message
{
   public List<string> Records { get; set; }
}
```

My message is:

```
var message = new Message() {Records = new List<string>()
{
   "Record 1",
   "Record 2",
   "Fault"
}};
```

And the consumer is:

```
public class MessageConsumer : IConsumer<Message>
{
   public MessageConsumer() {}

   public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
   {
      if (context.Message.Records.Any(m => m.Contains("Fault")))
      {
         var faultedRecords = context.Message.Records.Where(r => r.Contains("Fault")).ToList();

         // Message with faulted records only
         var errorMessage = new Message() { Records = faultedRecords };

         throw new Exception("Message has faulted records");
      }

      //...something else

      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

What is the right approach to sending `errorMessage` into `_error` queue? I khow about [Receive Pipeline](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/receive.html) but I can't choose the right place to change message content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit will move the entire message, as received from the transport, to the *_error* queue. Only headers can be added using middleware components on the receive pipeline. If you have individual records that fail to process, you should handle that record in the consumer (either catch the exception, or whatever) and produce your own event that another consumer can consume to handle the failed record.